# A',B',C' are midpoints of triangle sides BC, CA, AB and AD is altitude. Prove $\measuredangle B'DC'=\measuredangle B'A'C'$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, triangle-centres

$\triangle ABC$ is a triangle and A'B'C'  are  the midpoints of the sides $\overline{BC}, \overline{CA}$ and $\overline{AB}$ respectively. If $\overline{AD}$ is the altitude through $A$, prove that $\measuredangle B'DC'=\measuredangle B'A'C'$.

Hence. show that the circumcircle of $\Delta A'B'C'$ also passes through the feet $D, E, F$ of the altitudes of the $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I agree with @JoséCarlosSantos and I'd add that the title should also be improved.

Comment: @Bitan Saha I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I tried to use similarity and mid point theorem, but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Given the midpoints A', B' and C', the triangles B'CA' and ACB are similar, which leads to B'A' = $\frac12$AB = AC'. Similarly, C'A' = AB'.

Given that AD $\perp$ BC and $C'$, $B'$ are the midpoints, $C'$ and $B'$ are the centers of the circumcircles for the right triangles ABD and ACD, respectively.
Then,  DC' = AC' = A'B' and DB' = AB' = A'C'. Along with the shared side C'B', the triangles A'B'C' and DB'C' are congruent, which yields $\angle$C'DB' = ∠C'A'B'.

Comment: Could you please add a diagram to further elaborate your answer?

Comment: How are C' and B' centers of the circumcircle for the right triangles ABD and ACD respectively?

Comment: @BitanSaha - because ABD and ACD are right triangles, AB and AC are the diameters of the circumcircles.

Comment: Are D and A' the same points. If so, how?

Comment: @BitanSaha - They are not. ∠C'AB' = ∠C'A'B' because A', B' and C' are midpoints.

Comment: What has angle C'AB' being equal to  angle CA'B' got to do with point A' being a midpoint?

Comment: @BitanSaha - See the added in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: How are the two triangles B'CA' and ACB are similar?

Comment: @BitanSaha - Because the their side ratios is 1/2, along with the shared angle C